# Collecting data from two tables when one value is not part of the second table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm learning sql and foreign keys.
I'm now stuck with a task which I don't know how to proceed.

**Description:**
The task is to collect the name_id, name, lastname of table1 and game_id and game from table2 (see the tables bellow).

**Problem:**
I would use the name_id to collect the data from both tables using "WHERE table1.name_id = table2.name_id" but in that process name_id 3 will not appear because it has no connection to table2.

Code will appear like this missing name_id 3.

```
1       | name1| lastname1
2       | name2| lastname2
```

**Optimal outcome**

```
1       | name1| lastname1| 1| game1
2       | name2| lastname2| 2| game2
3       | name3| lastname3
```

Question:
How do I collect this value? Is it a logic problem or should I use JOIN to put them together?

```
table1
name_id | name | lastname
1       | name1| lastname1
2       | name2| lastname2
3       | name3| lastname3

table2
game_id | game | name_id
1       | game1| 1
2       | game2| 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using left outer join?

Comment: Hey! Yes, I tried it but it would not sort the information correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     using (name_id);
```